# Slow array operation in Powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell, logging, google-visualization, ping

I am working on a PowerShell script to convert ping log to chart data.

The script is working fine, but running very slowly caused by array operations.

If script executed on a 10k line file, it takes about 7 second. 
If array operation is removed, than it takes less then a sec to complete.

I am looking for alternative solution to return data to caller function without using temporary array.

Example of input log:

```
02.01.2017-14:53:54> Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=184ms TTL=57
02.01.2017-14:53:54> Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=18ms TTL=57
02.01.2017-14:53:59> Request timed out.
02.01.2017-14:54:01> Reply from 192.168.2.186: Destination host unreachable.
02.01.2017-14:54:05> Request timed out.
02.01.2017-14:54:07> Reply from 192.168.2.186: Destination host unreachable.
```

The Script:

```
function Convert-V4PingLog2ChartData
{
    param($V4PingLogFile, $AvarageRespondTime, $ChartCounter)
    $ConvertedData=""
    $var=Get-Content $V4PingLogFile
    $varArray=$var.split("`n")
    $varArray=$varArray | Select-Object -Skip 2

    $CommandExecuteTime=Measure-Command{

    $pattern = "^([0-9]{2})\.([0-9]{2})\.([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})> Reply from [0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}: bytes=32 time=([0-9]{1,4})ms TTL=[0-9]{1,3}$";
    $pattern2="^([0-9]{2})\.([0-9]{2})\.([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})> (Request timed out.|Reply from [0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}: Destination host unreachable.)$"

    foreach($nextLine in $varArray)
    {
        if($nextLine -like "* time=*")    
        {
            $ConvertedData+=$nextLine -replace $pattern, "data$ChartCounter.addRow([new Date(`$3, `$2, `$1, `$4, `$5, `$6,  00), `$7, $AvarageRespondTime]);"
        }
        else
        {
            $ConvertedData+=$nextLine -replace $pattern2, "data$ChartCounter.addRow([new Date(`$3, `$2, `$1, `$4, `$5, `$6,  00), 0, $AvarageRespondTime]);"
        }
    }
    }
    Write-Host $CommandExecuteTime
    return $ConvertedData
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you're appending to a string, not an array, but that's bound to be slow as well.

Change this:

```
$ConvertedData=""
...
foreach($nextLine in $varArray)
{
    if($nextLine -like "* time=*")    
    {
        $ConvertedData+=$nextLine -replace ...
    }
    else
    {
        $ConvertedData+=$nextLine -replace ...
    }
}
```

into this:

```
$ConvertedData = foreach ($nextLine in $varArray) {
    if ($nextLine -like "* time=*") {
        $nextLine -replace ...
    } else {
        $nextLine -replace ...
    }
}
$ConvertedData -join "`n"
```

to speed things up.

Comment: Thats a nice one Ansgar :)

Answer (score 1):

First, as Ansgar wrote, you are adding to a string and not an array. But the problem is the same in both cases. In .NET both arrays and strings are immutable (array sizes, not content). Every time you append something to an array or a string the system copies the old content to a new memory location and then appends the new data.

In arrays you can overcome this problem if you manually resize the array to the final size that you expect to be. The resize do copy the array, 
but it does it once and not at every append. The speed differences can be **HUGE**!

Lets consider the following command that appends 10000 items to an empty array:

```
$a = @(); Measure-Command { for($i = 0; $i -lt 10000; $i++) { $a += $i } }
```

Running this command I got the following results

```
Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 3
Milliseconds      : 534
Ticks             : 35342407
TotalDays         : 4,09055636574074E-05
TotalHours        : 0,000981733527777778
TotalMinutes      : 0,0589040116666667
TotalSeconds      : 3,5342407
TotalMilliseconds : 3534,2407
```

Now consider the following command. It first resizes the array using the Resize static member function of the Array object, and then sets the 10000 using indexing.

```
$b = @(); Measure-Command { 
    [array]::Resize([ref]$b,10000); 
    for($i = 0; $i -lt 10000; $i++) { $b[$i] = $i } 
}
```

The results are:

```
Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 0
Milliseconds      : 40
Ticks             : 402365
TotalDays         : 4,65700231481481E-07
TotalHours        : 1,11768055555556E-05
TotalMinutes      : 0,000670608333333333
TotalSeconds      : 0,0402365
TotalMilliseconds : 40,2365
```

The run time drop from 3.5 seconds to just 40 milliseconds!

You can combine this technique with the technique of Ansgar. Resize the array, add the results to the resized array and at the end join the array to a huge string.

Some remarks. You can call the resize as many time as you want, giving the new array size each time. You can get the current array size using the Length property of the array.
If you reach the limit and you need more space, just call the resize and add another big chunk.

I don't thing you will see much improvement, but if you really-really want to go as fast as possible you should go to the MSDN and take a look ta the Add to dictionary class. It's the recommended class for this kind of thinks, but it's not so easy to use it from PowerShell.

Comment: This one is super fast. Time to initialize 300K strings array went down from many minutes to fraction of a second. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

hi try Something like this:

```
$template=@"
{Timelog*:02.01.2017-14:53:54}> {TypeRow:Reply} {Detail:from {IP:8.8.8.8}: {Detailbytes:bytes=32} {Detailtime:time=184ms} {DetailTTL:TTL=57}}
{Timelog*:15.15.2018-20:30:00}> {TypeRow:Reply} {Detail:from {IP:18.28.38.48}: {Detailbytes:bytes=32} {Detailtime:time=184ms} {DetailTTL:TTL=57}}
{Timelog*:02.01.2017-14:53:54}> {TypeRow:Reply} {Detail:from {IP:1.2.345.678}: {Detailbytes:bytes=32} {Detailtime:time=184ms} {DetailTTL:TTL=57}}
{Timelog*:04.01.2017-14:53:59}> {TypeRow:Request} {Detail:{Message:timed out.}}
{Timelog*:03.01.2017-14:54:01}> {TypeRow:Reply} {Detail:from {IP:192.168.2.186}: {Message:Destination host unreachable.}}
{Timelog*:12.01.2017-14:54:05}> {TypeRow:Request} {Detail:{Message:timed out.}}
{Timelog*:02.01.2017-14:54:07}> {TypeRow:Reply} {Detail:from {IP:255.255.255.255}: {Message:Destination host unreachable.}}
"@

get-Content C:\temp\File.txt | ConvertFrom-String -TemplateContent $template |
%{
    [pscustomobject]@{
    Timelog=$_.Timelog
    TypeRow=$_.TypeRow
    IP=$_.Message.IP
    Detailbytes=if ($_.Detail.Message -ne $null) {''} else {$_.Detail.Detailbytes}
    Detailtime=if ($_.Detail.Message -ne $null) {''} else {$_.Detail.Detailtime}
    DetailTTL=if ($_.Detail.Message -ne $null) {''} else {$_.Detail.DetailTTL}
    Error=$_.Detail.Message 
    }
} | Format-Table
```

Comment: Thanks, nice solution and completely  different approaching :), I have tried on a 100K line log and only 23 sec.